# How to write a word letter by letter? Taking the word from an array

Tags: javascript

The word to write letter by letter should be taken in an array. I tried the code below, but it gives me this erorr `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined`. Also, the written word should be deleted for the next word, how can I do that? Thanks.

```js
let currentWord = -1;
let i = 0;
let words = ["Tree","Apple","Chair","Table"];
let curr = 0;

setInterval(Word, 2000)

function Word(){
    currentWord++;
    if(currentWord >= words.length){
        currentWord = 0;
    }
    let word = words[currentWord];
    Write(word)
}

let Write = function write(word){
    var elem = document.getElementById('word');
    elem.textContent += word.charAt(curr);
    curr++;
    if (curr < word.length)
        window.setTimeout(write, 100);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="cit.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="description">
        <h1>Hi <span id="word"></span></h1>
    </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `word()` function expects an argument, you aren't passing it in the `setTimeout` call.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you dont pass the current `word` back to the timouted `write` function. The line should read

```js
setTimeout(function(){ write(word); }, 100);
```

Edit:

To get rid of counting you can [remove the first letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) of the word you handle and print this. Then pass the rest of the word to the `write` function:

```js
function write(word) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('word');
    elem.textContent += word.shift();
    if (word.length > 0)
        window.setTimeout(function(){ write(word); }, 100);
};
```

Comment: Also note for OP: don't forget to reset `curr = 0;` once the word is written so you start the next one with its first letter

Comment: @WilbaltSlayerOfGargoyles Ok, it works. But, it doesn't write some letters, how can I fix that?

Comment: @Rafalon How can I do that? `curr = 0`

Comment: It would generally help to remove the first letter from the word you process right now and print it. That way you dont need to count anything and automatically stop when the word is written. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Frank something as simple as `if(curr < word.length) setTimeout else curr = 0` (short version)

Answer (score 0):

Your function write expects some word as argument. So when you call the function again from setTimeout, you would need to pass the current word again as argument.

So the line of code should be:

```
window.setTimeout(() => {
 Write(word)
}, 100);
```